# Como crear rutas en MAUI .NET 7 Maui maps

Tags: c#, api, .net, google-maps, maui

soy nuevo en el uso del API de Google MAPS, estoy desarrollando una aplicación en MAUI .NET 7, donde se muestra un mapa de google maps utilizando [MAUI.MAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map),
hasta ahora tengo mi mapa donde puedo marcar pines, polylines, medir distancias, etc. pero lo que no logro, es marcar la ruta de dos puntos algo así.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero no logro hacerlo utilizando Maui Maps, me gustaría saber si se pudiera usar algo como Routes API o Directions API?

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo Leaflet y OpenStreetMap, una alternativa a Google maps.
Te dejo un ejemplo: https://www.mapasvb.somee.com/

https://vbpuntonet.blogspot.com/2021/01/leaflet-y-oppenstreetmap-una.html

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción. y estos sirven para MAUI?